# Writing Images to a File Python

Tags: python, pdf, png

I have a folder of images (PNG format) that I want to write to one large file (e.g. PDF) with  the image and a caption for each of the images. It seems that writing this in a loop makes the most sense. Can anyone recommend a library and function that could be helpful in doing this? I have tried FPDF, and PdfPages. Thanks.

Comment: This is an off-topic question. You shouldn't question like this in SO.

Comment: Forgive me, but why is it off-topic? It's a perfectly good Python question. No reason to downvote.

Comment: Asking for code and library.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=Questions%20asking%20us%20to%20recommend%20or%20find%20a%20book%2C%20tool%2C%20software%20library%2C%20tutorial%20or%20other%20off%2Dsite%20resource%20are%20off%2Dtopic%20for%20Stack%20Overflow%20as%20they%20tend%20to%20attract%20opinionated%20answers%20and%20spam.%20Instead%2C%20describe%20the%20problem%20and%20what%20has%20been%20done%20so%20far%20to%20solve%20it.), asking for library IS off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The following will merge the images into one pdf, if that's what you intend to do

```
import os
from PIL import Image

def merge_into_pdf(paths, name):
    list_image = []
    # Create list of images from list of path
    for i in paths:
        list_image.append(Image.open(i).convert("RGB"))
    # merge into one pdf
    if len(list_image) == 0:
        return
    # get first element of list and pop it from list
    img1 = list_image[0]
    list_image.pop(0)
    # append all images and save as pdf
    img1.save(f"{name}.pdf",save_all=True, append_images=imagelist)

def main():
    # List directory
    directory = os.listdir(".")
    for k in directory:
        # if file ends with jpg or png append to list
              if k.endswith((".jpg", ".JPG", ".png", ".PNG")):
                    path.append(f"{k}")
        # merge list into one pdf
        merge_into_pdf(path, "name_of_new_file")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can easily use PIL to write captions into the images